# How to convert date --- Wed Feb 27 2019 11:11:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to 27-Feb-2019 format in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting date as **Wed Feb 27 2019 11:11:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** from date-picker. Now I have convert it to **27-Feb-2019** format. Please suggest me any simplest way for this.

var d=(date);
   alert(d);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H25oV.png)

Comment: use [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in javscript - if that doesn't do it for you, then there's always libraries like `moment.js` that make working with dates easy - also, *use a better date picker that returns a Date object rather than a string*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use moment library

```js
console.log(moment(new Date('Wed Feb 27 2019')).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));

console.log(moment(new Date('Wed Feb 27 2019 11:11:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)')).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the op wants it in `27-Feb-2019` format. change `MM` to `MMM`

Comment: Yaa. Thanks. missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment/dayjs/date-fns or similar libraries to format the date in a format you want.

An example with momentJs

```
moment('2014-08-20 15:30:00').format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this.

```js
  var  monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];
   var fromDate = new Date('Wed Feb 27 2019 11:11:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');
 
  var date =fromDate.getDate()+'-'+monthNames[fromDate.getMonth()]+'-'+fromDate.getFullYear();
alert(date )
console.log(date )
```

**Edit:**

1. **The getDate() method returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31) for the specified date.**
2. **The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.
   Note: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.**
3. **The getFullYear() method returns the year (four digits for dates between year 1000 and 9999) of the specified date.**

Comment: Thanks. It's Working

Answer (score 0):

It does not specifically require `React`

First create an object for mapping the month number with month name. Then using `Date` object convert the input and use `getDate` , `getMonth` & `getFullYear` functions to create the date in required format.

Also note the month starts with 0 , that mean `Jan` is `0` so adding 1 to it

```js
let mnthObj = {
  1: 'Jan',
  2: 'Feb',
  3: 'March',
  4: 'April'

}
let dt = new Date('Wed Feb 27 2019 11:11:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');

let conDtObj = `${dt.getDate()}-${mnthObj[dt.getMonth()+1]}-${dt.getFullYear()}`
console.log(conDtObj)
```